# SharkORM large data synchronization process

Tags: ios, sqlite, dbaccess

My company is developing an iOS order-taking app that needs to synchronize data with a cloud-based API. The data is relational, and we are struggling to find a solution that utilizes an ORM that is able to synchronize quickly. It is taking too long to loop through the download data, create/fetch models, and build the relationships. A single order record might have relationships to order line, customer, shipment, product, and other entities, and the sync process needs to fetch/create all of these related entities for each new/updated record, and it is very slow.

We already have a Java version of the application that uses ActiveJDBC as an ORM. We are able to insert data directly into the underlying SQLite database, and ActiveJDBC is capable of using the IDs and foreign keys that already exist on our API database. This allows us to insert the downloaded data a lot faster than building model objects.

As far as I can tell, SharkORM doesn't allow us to use an alternate database column for IDs and foreign keys. Is there any way to do something similar using SharkORM (or with a different iOS ORM)?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Id column is currently fixed and can't be changed.

You can use the raw execute function to supply a block of SQL, but it will be quite a bit of effort to achieve this.

To make things go faster, you could try these:

1. Batch into transactions
2. Disable the event model (makes things much .... much faster)
3. Delete the indexes temporarily
4. Execute a pragma, turning the synchronous features off (very fast but potentially dangerous)

Also, you can just ignore the Id column and create your own and index it, there is very little difference in the underlying way it would work.

Comment: Are you saying there is a raw execute function built into SharkORM? How do you go about using it? I don't see it mentioned in the documentation, but perhaps I am overlooking it. Thanks.